# Random events in Python

Tags: python

What is the best way to implement a random event in Python?

For example:

The variable **a** is set to 1 with a probability of 0.8 and otherwise to 2.

I've done this until now as following:

```
import random

a = 0 #Initialize a to 0

prob = random.random() #ask Python for a random float between 0 and 1

if prob < 0.8:
  a = 1
else:
  a = 2
```

Is there another way for such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
import random
a = random.choices([1, 2], weights=[0.8, 0.2])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy `random` with values and their probabilities

```
   from numpy.random import choice
   a = [0,2]
   output = choice(a, 1, p=[0.8,0.2])
   print(output)
```

Syntax: numpy.random.choice(list,k, p=None)

List: It is the original list from you have select random numbers.

k: It is the size of the returning list. i.e, the number of elements you want to select.

p: It is the probability of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use random.choices to make it a little more pythonic.

```
a = random.choices([1,2], weights = [4, 1])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Continuous form distribution

Continuous form distribution is [explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution), and grants you to have the **same probability** of extracting each value in the interval `[0, 1)`. That's exactly what you want to have: the probability of **80%** of getting `a=1` and **20%** of getting `a=2`.

## Numpy python implementation

Using *numpy.random.random_sample()* you can achieve this, from [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html):

> Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated
> interval.

```
import numpy as np

rand = np.random.random_sample() # sample output: 0.5320258785026352
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer to write your code like this:

```
import random

prob = random.random()
a = 1 if prob < 0.8 else 2
```